# React architectural problem - Best way of having a single global application state, updating child components when changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, architecture

I'm quite new to React, and I'm making a single page application with React.

So far, I've build the application with components and child components, having their own local state, however the child components doesn't really interact with one another, which is what I want them to, basically, with the least amount of boiler plate code...

**The problem** I'm facing, is that a change in some child component, should be able to update the state of another child component, somewhere else in the component tree.
A selection in one child component should also be able to trigger a function in another component updating it with data and so on.

I've considered having just one global application state, that all components can call and update when something in them changes, and this one application state will then update other components in the tree. Kinda like having a single "controller" with it's own state, that all components "views" can call, and which updates the states of other components as needed. (I'm used to WPF and MVC style of GUI programming).

**What I've considered:**

1. One could try to implement this with callback functions defined in the top of the hierarchy, to be sent down through the hierarchy and called from a child component when it changes.
   This method however results in a LOT of boilerplate code that just passes functions to their child components. It feels wrong and hard to maintain...
2. To avoid all this passing around and boilerplate code, I've tried using a [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), however this is not working as well as I hoped. I can only access the context from within the render function and from lifecycle functions, and sadly I often get complicated errors that are hard to understand. It seems like I'm exploiting React Context to do something you shouldn't use it for...
3. I've considered using a [singleton pattern](https://www.dofactory.com/javascript/singleton-design-pattern) in JavaScript, however then that singleton needs to have a reference to the root component, and query for the component it needs to change... This seems like kind of a hack, and may not be that pretty, but idk.
4. I'm considering trying out [React Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start) however it seems to work in many ways similar to React Context (I'll be honest, I haven't read much into it yet).

**What I need:**

I need to ask someone with greater React experience than me: How do you keep a global application state, and update child components based on changes to the global application state? Also: Am I thinking about this all wrong? Am I trying to do something in a non-react way, failing to see how I should do it in React?

Answer (score 1):

You can happily go with Redux or MobX, they're fine.

I suggest Taming The State from Robin Wieruch: https://roadtoreact.com/course-details?courseId=TAMING_THE_STATE

There are the book and the course. He shows different ways of handling React state.

Comment: Thanks! I was unaware of MobX. These frameworks seems to be the solution to my problem, and I'll read up on them :)

An interesting article about MobX vs. Redux: https://www.educba.com/mobx-vs-redux/

Answer (score 1):

Redux was created specifically for the problem yo stated.

Reacts follows a top-down down-top unidirectional flow in essence. Context API is useful in simple use cases but would fail horribly in a large scale application where you'd be creating consumers everywhere.

I'd suggest investing some time in Redux so that will save your precious time in long run.
There's a reason all big three frameworks require a state management library to be useful for large scale complex apps. (Angular has NgRx and Vue has Vuex).